# Convert INT to Array of Strings

Tags: arduino-nano

My sensor outputs an int. I would like this to be an array of strings so I can send it with my 433MHz transmitter.

Converting an int to a string to an array of strings seems to be extremely complicated. I've tried multiple approaches.

The error is always:

> array must be initialized with a brace-enclosed initializer

```
#include <VirtualWire.h>

const int led_pin = 11;
const int transmit_pin = 12;
const int receive_pin = 2;
const int transmit_en_pin = 3;
int mostureSensor = 0;

void setup()
{
  // Initialise the IO and ISR
  vw_set_tx_pin(transmit_pin);
  vw_set_rx_pin(receive_pin);
  vw_set_ptt_pin(transmit_en_pin);
  vw_set_ptt_inverted(true); // Required for DR3100
  vw_setup(1000);   // Bits per sec
}

byte count = 1;

void loop()
{
  // read the input on analog pin 0:
  String sensorValue = String(analogRead(mostureSensor));

  char charBuf[7];
  char msg[7] = sensorValue.toCharArray(charBuf, 7);

  //char msg[7] = {'h','a','l','l','o',' ','#'};
  Serial.println("sending");
  msg[6] = count;
  digitalWrite(led_pin, HIGH); // Flash a light to show transmitting
  vw_send((uint8_t *)msg, 7);
  vw_wait_tx(); // Wait until the whole message is gone
  digitalWrite(led_pin, LOW);
  delay(1000);
  count = count + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

toCharArray is a method. It will copy the value from SensorValur to charBuff, it won't return the char array.

Line:

```
 char msg[7] = sensorValue.toCharArray(charBuf, 7);
```

Should be:

```
 sensorValue.toCharArray(charBuf, 7);
```

charBuf will already have the sensorValue copied.

Check more about "toCharArray" method :

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/StringToCharArray